# Windows 10 Organization Configured PC unable to Access Local Shared Drive

Tags: azure-active-directory, shared-directory

I've inherited a mess from the IT "professional" I replaced and have been unable to successfully lobby for resources to setup a proper domain. I have Windows 10 PC's that are configured as "organizational" PC's not Personal, which allows our users to sign-in with their office365 accounts. 
However when they do this they are logged in via AzureAD\ Domain, I'm certain this is the reason they cannot access the shared drives my organization has been using. I would very much like to keep using this AzureAD setup but if I cannot access local network resources it won't work for me.

I've searched around but maybe I haven't been asking the right question to find a solution to my problem, or it's possible one doesn't exist which would be unfortunate.

Has anyone ran into this issue?

Is there a way to access non-AzureAD domain resources from an AzureAD\User Account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a DC (a virtual machine (VM) in the cloud or a physical server).
That DC has Azure Active Directory (AAD) Connect installed and configured on it. That creates an account in AD that synchronizes accounts and passwords with AAD.
When a computer joined to AAD logs in it sends the login request to AAD. AAD then validates that authentication request against the information synchronized from AD.
If you have workstations and laptops joined to AAD and they try to access a share on a server that is in a different domain than what AAD synchronizes with you are going to need to provide credentials that exist in the server which hosts the resources, you are trying to access.

There are a few right ways to do this as,

If the clients are in a single location and will always be in the same location as the DC then join them to the domain regularly. For clients that will be used in other locations join those computers to AAD and install AAD Connect in the DC.

If you want to move all the servers out of your office spin up a VM for your DC in Azure and deploy a cloud firewall in front of your VM. Create a Site-to-Site Virtual Private Network (VPN) between the cloud firewall and your office firewall. Now join computers that will always be in the office to the domain like normal, join computers that are going to be used remotely to AAD, and install AAD Connect on the DC.

Refer: [Windows 10 AAD Azure ad domain joined & SMB share](https://serverfault.com/questions/887759/windows-10-aad-azure-ad-domain-joined-smb-share), where similar discussion has been done